# Where can I find a list of Apple TV apps that can be installed in France?

Tags: appletv, streaming

I bought a French relative an Apple TV from the US as a gift. Until I can go there and see what the Apple TV App Store has to offer, I would love to see if there's a list of TV Apps that one can install in France to start giving them recommendations based on their tastes.

### Where can I find a list of French Apple TV apps?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your store country, you can search the App Store in any country using the marketing tools site, previously known as Link Maker.

#### https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store

Enter a search term and on the next page choose a store country and platform.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I'm confused as to what this tool is and how it works. What terms do you type in the search box? tvOS? App Store?

Comment: @Micro It's like you're browsing the App Store but with any storefront and platform. You don't need to search for ‘tvOS’ since there is an Apple TV dropdown to choose the platform to filter by.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot search for something that I don't know exists. This tool seems good if I know what I am looking for already. Here I would like a list of apps that exist on French Apple TV because every time I search a famous national network (TF1, M6, France Television being the leading national channels), there are no results. But also no usable results for the word "cinema" for example... Maybe there are very few TV channels for French tvOS and using it in France makes no sense? I would like to make sure... very hard to find anything at all so far .

Comment: This site seems to have changed, I don't see a way to browse by platform any longer.

Comment: @nohillside Still working fine for me, looks just like the screenshot. Would you post a screenshot of what you see in [chat] to compare with what I put in the answer?

Comment: @grg Ah, forget it, I didn't read the instructions. My bad.